# Can you tell me why show message “Resource not found” Microsoft Cognitive Face API in Android?

Tags: android, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have a problem, I just download this code https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android and take step all this page. But my app to show message "Resource not found" in Detection and other features.

[image]

[image]

[image]
In my azure portal ,I created Subscription , Group , Face API , I received key and Endpoint in this picture.

[image]
In my Android Studio, I put key and endpoint in this string.xml

[image]
In my gradle app.

Why this app is show message “Resource not found” ?

But I live in southeast asia.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the endpoint with the method , for ex,

If you need to detect face, you need to add "/detect" in the uri

```
https://tana29testface1.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect
```

Comment: Thank you for comment, I put url "https://tana29testface1.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/" sometimes worked and not worked, Can you tell why ?

Comment: you neeed to check the internal exception message, mark if the answer helped